# Downloading files in a webpage

Tags: html, file, download

I need to make the user able to download a file from my webpage on clicking a link on my website
I tried     `<a href='./image.ext'>Download file</a>`
By it just opened a new window and i need to right click  and select "save page as"
What I am expected is ,after clicking my link user must see a dialogue box "save as" as usual...How to do it..Is there any way in HTML to force download by showing such a dialogue

Note:Since stackoverflow is not allowing anchor tag,i just typed it as a.Please do not treat it as a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php to readfile() the file to the user.

this tutorial would be helpful for you : 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an Apache web server, you can use the `.htaccess` file to force file download for certain file extensions.  Add this line to your `.htaccess` to cause the "Save As" dialog to appear when the link is clicked:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .ext
```

If you wanted the same behaviour for a PDF or AVI, the following lines would do it:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is lame, but I found a solution [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/ht/download_link.htm)